# Validating a string of text to match a per-determinded format in java

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm attempting to write a validation method that will validate if someone has entered their license number in error, I've searched around and found some ideas but I just cant get the result that I want. The correct format should be TWO letters followed by SEVEN numbers, the two letters and seven numbers could change but the format should remain the same for exmaple:

> AB1234567

If the user entered this value then the boolean would be true, if they entered say:

> A12345678 or AB12345Y7 or even not matching the correct length  such as AB10

it would then return as false, my code that I've attempted is below, any help or push in the right direction is appreciated.

```
public boolean validateLicense() 
{
    boolean retValue = false;
    if ((this.licenseNumber.matches("[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{6}")))
        retValue = true;
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: You said SEVEN numbers, but have d{6}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you said seven numbers, but in regex, there is d{6}. And the second thing is that if you change that to:
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}
it will match that string too:
kjasd;lkfjAB1234567jklsdfa.
Your regex needs to be:
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}$

---

^ - start of the string
$ - end of the string

Code:

```
public boolean validateLicense() 
{
boolean retValue = false;
if ((this.licenseNumber.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{7}$")))
    retValue = true;
return retValue;
}
```

Comment: Although the use of ^ and $ is generally true for regular expressions, they're not needed here.  String.matches behaves exactly the same as Matcher.matches, which matches the entire string (effectively adding the ^ and $ for you)

Comment: Thank you, I'm still trying to learn all I can about using regex, I guess I still have a bit to go, I wouldn't have figured out the start and end of the string suggestion you provided. Also yes I cannot believe I did not see that my first mistake was that my number of digits was off, your a saint, again thank you!

Comment: Interesting @racraman so it dose not matter if I have it or not, it performs the same function?

Comment: Yes, it surprised me a bit at first as well.  It does actually matter, since if you wanted to find if a string CONTAINS a regex, you'd have to pad it with ".*" - eg. if "AB12345Y7" contains 3 digits (eg "123"), you'd have to say licenseNumber.matches(".*\\d{3}.*")   - EDITED to use regex rather than straight strings